# RoboVM does no generate classes from libgdx project

Tags: java, ios, xcode, libgdx, robovm

I'm working on a libgdx project that requires the addition of some native code. Ideally I wanted to compile what I have with RoboVM, open the project in xcode and then take off from there. The problem I have however is that when I open the project with xcode I find assets and a plist file but no code to work with.

For reference this is my launcher class in Android Studio, which is what was originally generated by the libgdx wizard save for the annotation at the top:

```
@CustomClass("IosLauncher")
public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate {
@Override
protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
        IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
        return new IOSApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
        UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
        pool.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my ios related bit of the gradle file:

```
project(":ios") {
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "robovm"


dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}
```

This is what I finally see when I select "Open Xcode Project" in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: What did you expect to see here? RoboVM actually does generate these, but not with "open xcode project" you should build your project (with gradle for instance) to actually generate classes (and with those the iOS app).

Comment: I expected to see objective-c code.

Comment: RoboVM is not a code translation tool, it actually runs java code using an ahead of time compiler in a vm on the iOS device. There is no objective-c code generated.